How to insert ffmpeg-0.6.7.tar.bz2 in qdvdauthor-2.4.1.orig.gz (qdvdauthor-2.4.1/qrender/ffmpeg-0.6.7) for debuild
On my own computer this works (debian/rules):
override_dh_auto_build:
cd .. && tar -xjf ffmpeg-0.6.7.tar.bz2 --directory $(CURDIR)/qrender

but on OBS (OpenSuSE Build Service) it doesn't:
in /usr/src/packages there is no ffmpeg-0.6.7.tar.bz2 file.
